An error occurred when using the xgboost as a classifier for hiclass
Bellow it's my example when using the xgboost classifier for hiclass. My question is specifically directed to the hiClass Python package for hierarchical classification. I would like to model the problem using hierarchical classification approach to proceed like in figure below:

How can I correct this error?
from hiclass import LocalClassifierPerParentNode
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
import numpy as np

X_train = np.array([
[40.7, 1. , 1. , 2. , 5. , 2. , 1. , 5. , 34.3],
[39.2, 0. , 2. , 4. , 1. , 3. , 1. , 2. , 34.1],
[40.6, 0. , 3. , 1. , 4. , 5. , 0. , 6. , 27.7],
[36.5, 0. , 3. , 1. , 2. , 2. , 0. , 2. , 39.9],
])

Y_train = np.array([
['Gastrointestinal', 'Norovirus', ''],
['Respiratory', 'Covid', ''],
['Allergy', 'External', 'Bee Allergy'],
['Respiratory', 'Cold', ''],
])

X_test = np.array([[35.5, 0. , 1. , 1. , 3. , 3. , 0. , 2. , 37.5]])

classifier = LocalClassifierPerParentNode(local_classifier=XGBClassifier(objective='multi:softmax'))
classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
predictions = classifier.predict(X_test)
print(predictions)

2024-05-07 14:19:52,005 - LCPPN - WARNING - Fitting ConstantClassifier for node 'Gastrointestinal'
2024-05-07 14:19:52,005 - LCPPN - WARNING - Fitting ConstantClassifier for node 'Gastrointestinal'
2024-05-07 14:19:52,005 - LCPPN - WARNING - Fitting ConstantClassifier for node 'Gastrointestinal'
2024-05-07 14:19:52,005 - LCPPN - WARNING - Fitting ConstantClassifier for node 'Gastrointestinal'
2024-05-07 14:19:52,005 - LCPPN - WARNING - Fitting ConstantClassifier for node 'Gastrointestinal'
2024-05-07 14:19:52,005 - LCPPN - WARNING - Fitting ConstantClassifier for node 'Gastrointestinal'
2024-05-07 14:19:52,005 - LCPPN - WARNING - Fitting ConstantClassifier for node 'Gastrointestinal'
2024-05-07 14:19:52,005 - LCPPN - WARNING - Fitting ConstantClassifier for node 'Gastrointestinal'
2024-05-07 14:19:52,005 - LCPPN - WARNING - Fitting ConstantClassifier for node 'Gastrointestinal'
2024-05-07 14:19:52,005 - LCPPN - WARNING - Fitting ConstantClassifier for node 'Gastrointestinal'
2024-05-07 14:19:52,024 - LCPPN - WARNING - Fitting ConstantClassifier for node 'Norovirus'
2024-05-07 14:19:52,024 - LCPPN - WARNING - Fitting ConstantClassifier for node 'Norovirus'
2024-05-07 14:19:52,024 - LCPPN - WARNING - Fitting ConstantClassifier for node 'Norovirus'
2024-05-07 14:19:52,024 - LCPPN - WARNING - Fitting ConstantClassifier for node 'Norovirus'
2024-05-07 14:19:52,024 - LCPPN - WARNING - Fitting ConstantClassifier for node 'Norovirus'
2024-05-07 14:19:52,024 - LCPPN - WARNING - Fitting ConstantClassifier for node 'Norovirus'
2024-05-07 14:19:52,024 - LCPPN - WARNING - Fitting ConstantClassifier for node 'Norovirus'
2024-05-07 14:19:52,024 - LCPPN - WARNING - Fitting ConstantClassifier for node 'Norovirus'
2024-05-07 14:19:52,024 - LCPPN - WARNING - Fitting ConstantClassifier for node 'Norovirus'
2024-05-07 14:19:52,024 - LCPPN - WARNING - Fitting ConstantClassifier for node 'Norovirus'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 24
     21 classifier = LocalClassifierPerParentNode(local_classifier=XGBClassifier(objective='multi:softmax'))
     23 # Train local classifier per node
---> 24 classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
     26 # Predict
     27 predictions = classifier.predict(X_test)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hiclass/LocalClassifierPerParentNode.py:109, in LocalClassifierPerParentNode.fit(self, X, y)
    106 self._initialize_local_classifiers()
    108 # Fit local classifiers in DAG
--> 109 self._fit_digraph()
    111 # TODO: Store the classes seen during fit
    112 
    113 # TODO: Add function to allow user to change local classifier
   (...)
    120 
    121 # Delete unnecessary variables
    122 self._clean_up()

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hiclass/LocalClassifierPerParentNode.py:348, in LocalClassifierPerParentNode._fit_digraph(self)
    346     self.hierarchy_.nodes[node]["classifier"] = ConstantClassifier()
    347     classifier = self.hierarchy_.nodes[node]["classifier"]
--> 348 classifier.fit(X, y)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/core.py:730, in require_keyword_args.<locals>.throw_if.<locals>.inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
    728 for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args):
    729     kwargs[k] = arg
--> 730 return func(**kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py:1471, in XGBClassifier.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, base_margin, eval_set, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose, xgb_model, sample_weight_eval_set, base_margin_eval_set, feature_weights, callbacks)
   1466     expected_classes = self.classes_
   1467 if (
   1468     classes.shape != expected_classes.shape
   1469     or not (classes == expected_classes).all()
   1470 ):
-> 1471     raise ValueError(
   1472         f"Invalid classes inferred from unique values of `y`.  "
   1473         f"Expected: {expected_classes}, got {classes}"
   1474     )
   1476 params = self.get_xgb_params()
   1478 if callable(self.objective):

ValueError: Invalid classes inferred from unique values of `y`.  Expected: [0 1], got ['Respiratory::HiClass::Separator::Cold'
 'Respiratory::HiClass::Separator::Covid']

